# Regex to check a string has only those values not less or more

Tags: regex

I've few contents in database like,

```
who is <i>Alisha</i>?
who is <i>Alisha</i> mother?
who is <i>Alisha</i> father?
What is her job<sup>®</sup>?
```

When I enter the values in search field I'm stripping the html contents. 
So my search is who is Alisha?

I would like to check for the exact words and would like to show the search result as Who is Alisha only.

Bu which regular expression I can get the search result exactly the same. Also when someone search for who, it has to list all questions that contain who..

Is it possible and can anyone help me with this?

Comment: When you say "database," do you mean "relational database," or "nosql database" or just "text file one per line"? Because the first two products generally provide some kind of string searching capabilities, but it varies product by product.

Comment: Check Fuzzy search libraries in whatever language you are doing this. Also check [`Apache Solr`](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

Comment: What Regex flavor, what are you trying to achieve? Please clarify your question. What search field are you talking about. Is each line a database entry? Do you type "who is Alisha" in your search field? Why should the result say "Who is Alisha", neither your database nor your search has a capitalized W. etc.

Comment: @CodeMonkey I've an auto complete field. It will show the suggestions in drop down. On clicking any of those values in dropdown as as "Who is alisha". It must search in database, mysql , where it is stored as "Who is <i>alisha</i>". And only show this result. Not any other, something that sonly contain exact same strings with no html.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try REGEX function in Relational Database 
something like  - REGEX('^who is *Alisha $')

StartWith Who is and End with Alisha